# how sum column group by jsonḃ postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

Hi I have a colum jsnoḃ with this values

```
proyectos:
nomḃre:character_varying
fecha:datetime
campos: jsonḃ
```

the value of campos is =

```
{"lista": [{"valor": "10", "nombre": "sueldo"}, {"valor": "20", "nombre": "sueldo"}, {"valor": "25", "nombre": "sueldo"}]}
```

I I run this query ḃut not working

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(campos->'lista')->'nombre' as content,

       sum(((jsonb_array_elements(campos->'lista')->'valor'))::numeric) as cantidad
 FROM proyectos GROUP BY jsonb_array_elements(campos->'lista')->'nombre
```

The console  show me the message:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type jsonb to numeric
LINE 3: ...((jsonb_array_elements(campos->'lista')->'valor'))::numeric)...
                                                             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: cannot cast type jsonb to numeric
SQL state: 42846
Character: 137
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Why is there a `.` above every `b` of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `jsonb_array_elements()` in a lateral join to get array elements as `value`, the `->>` operator to get json objects as text and cast the `valor` objects to numeric.

```
select value->>'nombre' as nombre, sum((value->>'valor')::numeric)
from proyectos
cross join jsonb_array_elements(campos->'lista')
group by 1

 nombre | sum 
--------+-----
 sueldo |  55
(1 row)
```

Comment: This means *group by first column* and is the same as `group by value->>'nombre'`